# Is storing electronics in high temperatures different than operating them in high temperatures?

Tags: hardware-failure, temperature, overheating

This may be a weird topic for SU but for those of us who are on the go a lot proving tech support or just carry our gear because we can and it is nice to always have around and with us, **is storing hardware and electronics in 90F+ degree car trunks in backpacks a bad idea?** Hardware meaning: switches, hard drives, routers, and other little devices with circuits.

I know they should never operate in those temperature ranges but is storing the same thing?

I understand that laptop batteries are effected by heat due to how they are built, but not sure about electronics that are not running.

Comment: You may be greatly underestimating the temperature inside the car if it's 90F degrees outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the components of computer systems designed for higher operating temperatures. Since the HDD ending memory.

It can be found in the reports and investigation of large data centers, such as the same Google.

Even in most cases, the processor begins its cooling to 22 C (71.6 ° F) if it is not installed Peltier element.

If you suddenly need a source of cold in the car, from the heat source is always possible to build a refrigerator. For example, absorption chiller (heat pumps). Depending on the mixture refrigerants such as ammonia (poison), or lithium bromide (a sedative with possible fatal effect for cardiac patients)

You may get a temperature of -45 C (-49 ° F ammonia) to +3 C (37.4 ° F LiB) degrees. At negative temperatures have questions dehumidification, to protect against frost and condensation. The system of heat exchangers and ducts will enable the distribution of temperature inside the vehicle.

In essence, the vehicle is a refrigerator on wheels.

Accordingly, you can force the cooling of the battery and processor.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, it's different in my experience. I used to work on a survey ship operating in west Africa, and humidity was a big problem in some cases. We weren't just pushing the hardware operating limits, we were pretty much forced to ignore them and hope for the best. In my experience, active equipment didn't last as long as inactive equipment, even if all external factors were the same.

Equipment that had been exposed to very high temperatures and humidity worked just fine, if it was stored for a few days in a cool and dry environment before use, so that any humidity that had built up inside was removed.

In your case, this depends a lot on the electronics in question. For example, batteries can be dangerous if too hot, but 90F isn't that much. I would say that purely from a temperature perspective, your gear will be fine. If the air isn't very humid, it is unlikely to take any damage from it, especially if it is only for storage.